# How do I code a form field to be hidden but still have the value show for the recipient of the form information?

Tags: html, forms, hidden

My client has this very simple form that they want the last three input fields to not be seen (hidden) but their preset value show up and propagate their SalesForce dashboard. I've tried several ways of doing this but nothing wants to work and it even breaks the SUBMIT path. Any suggestions of how to make these forms cleaner and working would be greatly appreciated as they will need several of these forms set up.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato+Sans+SC:300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function MM_validateForm() { //v4.0
      if (document.getElementById) {
        var i, p, q, nm, test, num, min, max, errors = '',
          args = MM_validateForm.arguments;
        for (i = 0; i < (args.length - 2); i += 3) {
          test = args[i + 2];
          val = document.getElementById(args[i]);
          if (val) {
            nm = val.name;
            if ((val = val.value) != "") {
              if (test.indexOf('isEmail') != -1) {
                p = val.indexOf('@');
                if (p < 1 || p == (val.length - 1)) errors += '- ' + nm + ' must contain an e-mail address.\n';
              } else if (test != 'R') {
                num = parseFloat(val);
                if (isNaN(val)) errors += '- ' + nm + ' must contain a number.\n';
                if (test.indexOf('inRange') != -1) {
                  p = test.indexOf(':');
                  min = test.substring(8, p);
                  max = test.substring(p + 1);
                  if (num < min || max < num) errors += '- ' + nm + ' must contain a number between ' + min + ' and ' + max + '.\n';
                }
              }
            } else if (test.charAt(0) == 'R') errors += '- ' + nm + ' is required.\n';
          }
        }
        if (errors) alert('The following error(s) occurred:\n' + errors);
        document.MM_returnValue = (errors == '');
      }
    }
    //-->
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table width="1000" height="283" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">

        <form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" onsubmit="MM_validateForm('first_name','','R','last_name','','R','company','','R','email','','R');return document.MM_returnValue">

          <input type=hidden name='captcha_settings' value='{"keyname":"reCAPTCHAv2","fallback":"true","orgId":"00D2E0000012vq0","ts":""}'>
          <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D2E0000012vq0">
          <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="https://levelcapital.com/thank-you/">
          <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
          <!--  NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment    -->
          <!--  these lines if you wish to test in debug mode.                          -->
          <!--  <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>                              -->
          <!--  <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail"                                  -->
          <!--  value="molly@levelcapital.com">                                         -->
          <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
          <label for="first_name">First Name<span class="style2">*</span></label>
          <input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" />
          <br />
          <label for="last_name">Last Name<span class="style2">*</span></label>
          <input id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" />
          <br />
          <label for="company">Company<span class="style2">*</span></label>
          <input id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" />
          <br />
          <label for="phone">Phone</label>
          <input name="phone" type="phone" id="phone" onblur="MM_validateForm('phone','','NisNum');return document.MM_returnValue" size="20" maxlength="40" />
          <br />
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <span class="style2">*</span>
          <input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="email" />
          <br /> Purchase or Refinance?:
          <select id="00N2E00000J9pb3" name="00N2E00000J9pb3" title="Purchase or Refinance?">
            <option value="">--None--</option>
            <option value="Purchase">Purchase</option>
            <option value="Refinance">Refinance</option>
          </select>
          <br /> Lien Amount:
          <input name="00N2E00000JCf6O" type="text" id="00N2E00000JCf6O" onblur="MM_validateForm('00N2E00000JCf6O','','NisNum');return document.MM_returnValue" size="20" />
          <br /> Loan Type:
          <select id="00N2E00000IBNJ6" name="00N2E00000IBNJ6" title="Loan Type">
            <option value="">--None--</option>
            <option value="Construction">Construction</option>
            <option value="Bridge Loan">Bridge Loan</option>
            <option value="Acquisition">Acquisition &amp; Development</option>
          </select>
          <br /> Property Type:
          <select id="00N2E00000ItX4D" name="00N2E00000ItX4D" title="Property Type">
            <option value="">--None--</option>
            <option value="Single Family">Single Family</option>
            <option value="Land">Land</option>
            <option value="Townhome">Townhome</option>
            <option value="Multi Family">Multi Family</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
          </select>
          <br /> Number of Units:
          <input name="00N2E00000HFNPg" type="text" id="00N2E00000HFNPg" onblur="MM_validateForm('00N2E00000HFNPg','','NisNum');return document.MM_returnValue" size="20" />
          <br /> Square Footage Per Unit:
          <input name="00N2E00000IBNJF" type="text" id="00N2E00000IBNJF" onblur="MM_validateForm('00N2E00000IBNJF','','NisNum');return document.MM_returnValue" size="20" />
          <br /> Est. Loan Value:
          <input name="00N2E00000JCf6Y" type="text" id="00N2E00000JCf6Y" onblur="MM_validateForm('00N2E00000JCf6Y','','NisNum');return document.MM_returnValue" size="20" />
          <br /> Est. Loan Cost:
          <input name="00N2E00000JCf6s" type="text" id="00N2E00000JCf6s" onblur="MM_validateForm('00N2E00000JCf6s','','NisNum');return document.MM_returnValue" size="20" />
          <br /> Proposed Loan Term:
          <input name="00N2E00000JCf7H" type="text" id="00N2E00000JCf7H" onblur="MM_validateForm('00N2E00000JCf7H','','NisNum');return document.MM_returnValue" size="20" />
          <br /> Potential Funding Date:<span class="dateInput dateOnlyInput">
<input name="00N2E00000J9pb2" type="text" class="date"  id="00N2E00000J9pb2" onblur="MM_validateForm('00N2E00000J9pb2','','NisNum');return document.MM_returnValue" value="MM/DD/YYYY" size="12" color:"#CCCCCC"/>
</span><br /> Site Address:
          <textarea id="00N2E00000HFNPv" name="00N2E00000HFNPv" rows="3" type="text" wrap="soft"></textarea>
          <br /> Parcel Number:
          <input id="00N2E00000HFO1G" maxlength="250" name="00N2E00000HFO1G" size="20" type="text" />
          <br /> Permit Status:
          <input id="00N2E00000HFNQ5" maxlength="255" name="00N2E00000HFNQ5" size="20" type="text" />
          <br />
          <label for="description">Description</label>
          <textarea name="description"></textarea>
          <br />
          <!------------------------------------------------------------------start hidden here------------------------------------------------------------>
          <table width="600" height="63" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" type="hidden">
            <tr>
              <td><input name="lead_source" type="hidden" id="lead_source" value="WadeStewart" />
                <br />

                <input name="Builder/Borrower Opportunities" type="hidden" id="recordType" value="0122E000000Kfhc" />
                <br />

                <input name="state" type="hidden" id="state" value="FL" />
                <br /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <!------------------------------------------------------------------end hidden here--------------------------------------------------------------->
          <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcSsAkbAAAAABI0maF70xvgp1HZh5LNl2pxDi0S"><br/>
            <input name="Submit" type="submit" onclick="MM_validateForm('first_name','','R','last_name','','R','company','','R','email','','RisEmail');return document.MM_returnValue" value="Submit" />
            <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="button" value="Reset" />
          </div>
        </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="50" colspan="2">
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the hidden inputs, it is the fact your form tag is invalid HTML. Proper indenting will show you your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<input type="hidden">
```

Hidden inputs can be used anywhere that you want to include data the user can't see along with the form when it's submitted to the server.